# Assembler How can i get acces to the elements of array?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I have problem with an Assembler (16-bits)
When I type 'abc' it return me abc too. The question is, how can I get access to 'a' (first element) ?
Can I use stack (to chars)?

```
org 100h

Start:
mov ah,0ah
mov dx,input
int 21h

mov ah,9
mov dx,label
int 21h
mov ah,9
mov dx,input+2
int 21h

End:
mov ax,4c00h
int 21h

label db 10,13,"Your characters: $"
input db 6
db 0
times 8 db "$"
```

Comment: You used print string function. You can of course load individual bytes and print them one at a time.

Comment: after input (`int 21h` service), the string is stored in memory, in that buffer reserved by `times 8 db "$"`, which did initialize 8 bytes with value 36. So you can access it by any instruction accessing memory, like `mov al,[input+2]` will load value `97` into register `al`. (97 = `'a'` in ASCII encoding). Or `mov ax,[input+3]` will load `ax` with `0x6362` (i.e. `al = 'b'`, and `ah = 'c'`) (for input "abc"), and at address `input+5` there will be value `13` ("enter" or more precisely in DOS "carriage return"). (you can also use stack, although it's hard to imagine what exactly you mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course.
Your string is just a sequence of bytes.

The easier way is to actually name all the part of the structure used by the `Int 21h/AH=0ah` service:

```
label db 10,13,"Your characters: $"

input    db 6
str_len  db 0
string:  times 8 db "$"
```

then:

`mov al, BYTE [str_len]` can be used to load the string's length in `al` (any 8-bit register will do).
`mov al, BYTE [string + X]` will load the `(X + 1)th` char of the string in `al` (for `X` known at assemble time - i.e. static).
`mov bx, X` + `mov al, BYTE [string + bx]` will load the `(X + 1)th` char of the string in  `al` (for `X` known at runtime - i.e. dynamic).

Comment: Thanks! Another question, how to implement your X?

Comment: @Michael If you want the first character `X` is 0, for the second char `X` is 1 and so on.

Comment: @Michael Hard to say, the code seems correct. Maybe is something else near it?

Comment: Everything is ok ;) Thank you a lot ::)

Comment: @Michael `div ax, ax` is not a valid instruction. It's unclear how that would be related to zeroing a register. The best way to do it is with `xor` anyway. You can search StackOverflow for the canonical question about zeroing.

Comment: Ohh my fault. Of course I mean about xor ;) Why is that better than other?

Comment: @Michael See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and/33668295#33668295).